# Best fit linear regression function using R

Tags: r, regression, linear-model

I'm trying to learn linear regression and how to fit the best model (drop non-significant variables and include interaction terms)

I used a subset of the pisa dataset and am trying to predict the reading score.

```
year country television math read
<dbl> <fctr> <fctr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
2018    AUS     2   253.056 353.258 
2018    AUS     3+  609.103 521.900 
2018    AUS     3+  398.535 408.911 
2018    AUS     3+  418.239 310.553 
2018    AUS     3+  664.577 687.343 
2018    AUS     3+  541.329 611.386 
2018    AUS     1   617.026 641.578 
2018    AUS     3+  562.511 418.865 
2018    AUS     2   477.485 474.356 
2018    AUS     2   396.637 485.595
```

Right now I'm manually including different combinations of variables and interaction terms using the following approach.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)

lm_mod <- linear_reg() %>%
  set_engine("lm")

lm_fit <- lm_mod %>% 
  fit(read ~ year + country + television + math + country*television, data = data)
```

Is there an easier way to compare all possible combinations?
Any suggestions to evaluate the models is also appreciated.

Comment: You should look into stepwise regression using e. g. the `step()` function or `MASS::stepAIC`. It does not try all possible combinations (combinatorics quickly leads to large numbers!) but does stepwise inclusion/exclusion of predictors as long aus the AIC is shrinking. Be warned, that stepwise or trying all combinations has a high risk of overfitting your model to the random sample. This is why stepwise regression is usally disencouraged. So try it out but do not publish results until you have done a considerable amount of reading about it!

Comment: You may also want to consider running best subsets selection using the leaps package:  http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/37-model-selection-essentials-in-r/155-best-subsets-regression-essentials-in-r/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written in my comment, that stepwise regression may be the alternative to the original question of trying all possible combinations of predictors. I have also warned of overfitting.

Though this is not strictly an answer I need the space and syntax highlighting for an explanation with code.

Consider a 40 x 30 tibble full of random data like so:

```
set.seed(1234)
library(tibble)
data <- as_tibble(matrix(runif(1200),ncol=30))
data
```

Now all these are random data and nothing should be a predictor of anything else. Let's still try to predict column 1 aka `V1` from the other 29 columns:

```
set.seed(1234)
library(tibble)
data <- as_tibble(matrix(runif(1200),ncol=30))
model <- lm(V1~ ., data = data)
summary(model)
```

The overall p value is .197, not significant as it should be: there is no explaining structure in these data. There are however roughly 536870911 possible models here to try. We do not want to try them all, so we use stepwise regression instead:

```
set.seed(1234)
library(tibble)
data <- as_tibble(matrix(runif(1200),ncol=30))
model <- lm(V1~ ., data = data)
summary(model)

step(model)
```

`step` first eliminates `V30`, in the next step it eliminates `V26`, then `V23` and so on. The final proposition is

```
lm(formula = V1 ~ V2 + V3 + V4 + V5 + V7 + V8 + V10 + V11 + V12 + 
V13 + V14 + V15 + V17 + V19 + V20 + V22 + V24 + V25 + V28 + 
V29, data = data)
```

And if we investigate that, we get an overall p = .001 with R-squared of 62.9% and lot's of highly significant predictors. Even though we know, that we had only random numbers with no connection between columns, yet we can "proove" the significant influence of rows `V2`, `V3` etc on `V1`. Except that all we prooved is fluff. By the magic of overfitting, this model will turn from R-squared > 60% within the sample to no predictive value at all for new data.

There are lot's of threads on choosing predictors but trying all and everything or stepwise regression is probably not the way you should go.